# QML ListView and key navigation - handling of single key events

Tags: c++, qt, events, keyboard, qml

I'm using Qt 5.6.2 (Windows 10) and have a `QObject`-derived mapper that sends `QKeyEvent`s to the currently focused QML item. My base class has a virtual `mapToKey()` function which is then override in the various mappers I want to use. For example the mapping function below is part of my `LeftArrowMapper` and sends left arrow key events:

```
void LeftArrowMapper::mapToKey()
{
    // Retrieve root of QML context
    QObject* root = engine->rootObjects()[0];
    // Get currently focused item
    QQuickItem *item = (root->property("activeFocusItem")).value<QQuickItem *>();
    if (item == NULL) qDebug() << "No item";

    // Create a key and a key event
    Qt::Key key = Qt::Key_Left;
    QKeyEvent* event = new QKeyEvent(QKeyEvent::KeyPress,
                                     key,
                                     Qt::NoModifier,
                                     KeySequence(key).toString());

    // Send it to the focused QML item
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(item,event);
}
```

If the given item supports key events, it will react accordingly. Otherwise the received key events will not trigger any response. I've tested it with `TextField`, a custom `Text`-based component (that simply updates the `text` property with the text sent through the key event) etc. and I haven't encountered any issues. Until I started working with a `ListView`...

I'm trying to navigate a `ListView` using the keyboard's left and right arrow keys with the key events being artificially created using my `mapToKey()` function of my mapper (the point here: **map hardware events like pressing real buttons to Qt events**). In Qt 5.6 setting the `focus` property to `true` enables the navigation with keys (in 5.8 and probably also 5.7 the `keyNavigationEnabled` property has to be set to `true`; there is no such property in Qt 5.6).

My `ListView` looks as follows:

```
ListView {
    id: list
    orientation: Qt.Horizontal
    width: rootWindow.width
    height: 50

    Keys.onPressed: {
        console.log("list: " + event.key + " : " + event.text)
        if (event.key == Qt.Key_Left) console.log("Moving to the left");
        else if (event.key == Qt.Key_Right) console.log("Moving to the right");
    }

    model: ListModel {
        id: items
    }
    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: 50
        height: 50
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "[" + name + "]"
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: function() {
        for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            items.append({"name" : i});
        }
    }
    onFocusChanged: {
        console.log("List focus has changed");
    }
}
```

The problem I have discovered is the strange way key events are handled by this QML component. It seems that it tries to mimic the kinetic-based swipe (acceleration is taken into consideration) that you can do with your mouse when scrolling through the items in it. This means the following:

- Scrolling the view is triggered if an arrow key is held for a long period of time (approx. **2 seconds**) - once enabled it doesn't scroll a single item but multiple
- After the scrolling mentioned above is triggered the user can continue pressing the arrow key to continue the fast scrolling. At this point scrolling a single item per key event is also possible but...
- Changing the direction leads to a reset of the behaviour described above so the user needs to do another "trigger scroll" event in order to scroll in the opposite direction
- Triggering multiple separate key events also triggers the scrolling but this time single item at a time. Also the time interval I've mentioned above doesn't seem to apply here. The user needs to press the given arrow key 7 times (at least this is how many I've counted) before he can select the next/previous item in the list

It seems that internally the mapping requires a certain amount of **press-and-release** or **press-and-hold-for-X-seconds** key events to actually trigger some response in the `ListView`.

Now a colleague of mine created a custom key navigation of the `ListView` we are using and it works fine. However I'm wondering if there isn't some secret setting (or perhaps we have both missed the memo in the documentation) which handles this. I can see the application of such type of interaction with keys (that is emulating acceleration) but for the scenario I'm working on I really don't need it or at least not for now. Plus it would be really useful to know how things are done in case I want to add the pseudo-acceleration part at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kinetic-based swipe in `ListView` when you press left/right arrow key is the animation from [`ListView.highlight`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#highlight-prop). To make it visible, we can add some code to your list:

```
ListView {
    id: list

    Keys.onPressed: {
        console.log(list.currentIndex);
        //...
    }
    delegate: Item { // so we can see highlight in background
        width: 50
        height: 50
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "[" + name + "]"
        }
    }
    highlight: Rectangle {
        width: 50
        height: 50
        color: "pink"
    }
    //...
}
```

When you press right arrow key, `currentIndex` is changed and the highlight moves to that index. You can see the same animation if you explicitly change `currentIndex` like this:

```
Button {
    text: "go to 45"
    onClicked: list.currentIndex = 45;
}
```

To customize the animation, you can change `ListView.highlightMoveDuration` and `ListView.highlightMoveVelocity` properties, or set `ListView.highlightFollowsCurrentItem` to false to turn it off. You can also follow the [`ListView` example code](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-views-example.html#highlight) to make your own highlight animation.

> It seems that internally the mapping requires a certain amount of press-and-release or press-and-hold-for-X-seconds key events to actually trigger some response in the `ListView`.

There's no magic in `ListView` when handling key events, it simply changes `currentIndex` constantly and animations in QML can handle it perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. Adding a `console.log` in the `Key.onPressed` indeed showed a change in `currentIndex`. I just wasn't seeing that change since I had no highlighting and the list scrolling became visible only when the currentIndex reached the end of the view. :D